# ExtJS 6 Charts -- change background color

Tags: html, css, extjs

I am trying to change the white background color for my charts in ext 6. I inspected the x-surface-canvas class and changed the background color like so:

```
.x-surface-canvas{
  background:red;
}
```

This works and changes the background color to red but then you cant see the chart anymore. The axis and series all get hidden by the background color. The background color seems to be defaulting to transparent which shows a white background (even though the body of my app has a dark gray bg) and if I change transparent to any other color, the chart gets hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`background`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.chart.PolarChart-cfg-background) property.

[Working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15mq)